# Adding a loading image to a jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading-image

i have the following javascript to post a form through ajax without refreshing the screen.  Since the post take a little while, i wanted to add a loading image during processing.

I see [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-loading-image/) but it seems to only list .load() or .get() but not $.post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact form').live('submit', function() {

            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {

                $("#contact").replaceWith($(data));

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add a few calls to hide/show your load screen/div, whatever:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#contact form').live('submit', function() {
            $("#Loading").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#contact").replaceWith($(data));
                $("#Loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide when data's ready
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="Loading">I'm loading, image here, whatever you want</div>
```

Comment: @Nick Craver - i upvoted this as it worked but one follow up question.  is there anyway to have this loading image showed overlayed in the center on top of the form as right now its below it which looks a little weird

Comment: @oo - You can do it with CSS/positioning or...you can use something like blockUI for this perhaps: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element  In that case you call `$(this).block({ message:$("#Loading") });` and `$('#contact form').unblock();` for the second call.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in so that is shows on every ajax call, no matter which one I have (I have several)

```
/* show the message that data is loading on every ajax call */
var loadingMessage = 'Please wait loading data for ' + defaultPageDoctor;
$(function()
{
    $("#Errorstatus")
    .bind("ajaxSend", function()
        {
            $(this).text(loadingMessage);
            $(this).show();
        })
    .bind("ajaxComplete", function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Just create an element with the #ErrorStatus id such as:

```
<div class="newProcedureErrorStatus ajaxLoading " id="newProcedureErrorStatus">
    <span id="Errorstatus" class="ui-state-error-text newProcedureErrorStatusText"></span>
    <span id="Errorstatus2" class="ui-state-error-text newProcedureErrorStatusText">
    </span>
</div>
```

Now for the bonus rounds, you can use this area to put other messages up, I also include a timer:

```
/* show message for interval */
var saveMessageText = 'Saving...';
function ShowStatus(saveMessage, message, timeInMilliseconds)
{
    var errorMessage = $("#Errorstatus");
    if (saveMessage)
    {
        errorMessage.show();
        //var myNumber = 0;
        var myInterval = window.setInterval(function()
        {
            message = message + '...';
            errorMessage.text(message);
            errorMessage.show();
        }, 1000);
        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            errorMessage.hide();
        }, timeInMilliseconds);
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage.text(message);
        errorMessage.show();
        window.setTimeout('$("#Errorstatus").hide()', timeInMilliseconds);
    };
};
```

use it like so:

```
 ShowStatus(true, 'Save Failed with unknown Error', 4000);
```