# .NET MVC3 : Avoid to close view-window while controler is still loading data

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, confirmation

.NET MVC 3: I need to prevent the user from closing the *view* window while the controller is still working (for instance loading data from the database). Confirmation message would be fine for me but I think I can't handle that by using window.onbeforeunload event (it's before *return View()* statement). Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to pop up a loading image.  Keep the image up until the DB finishes it job and then hide that image.

Here is a link to one I found after a quick Google search.  [Loading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351209/adding-a-loading-image-to-a-jquery-ajax-post)

Comment: Iya, thanks for your answer. But I think it's not a question of loading image. I need to disable closing the explorer window while data are loading.

Comment: Blocking them from closing the window is not always a good idea...  I understand helping protect the user's from themselves and from loss of data, but if the user makes the decision to close while a loading screen is up, that is usually on them for not paying attention, not you.